# Specify columns in INNER JOINed table

Tags: php, mysql

**comment** table and **post** table both has column named **user_id**

I cannot specify both table's **user_id**

for using some if else condition later I need both the user_id as a different name (I'm trying to use AS).

I tried different way but query not working:

```php
$sql="SELECT `post_id`, `comment_id`, `comment`, `user_id`, `username`,
 `is_marked` `post`.`user_id` AS `p_uid` FROM `comment` INNER JOIN `user` ON
 `comment`.`user_id` = `user`.`id` INNER JOIN `post` ON 
`user`.`id`=`post`.`user_id` ORDER BY `comment_id` DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
if ($result) {
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$post_user_id = $row['p_uid'];
```

Comment: Hi please read this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query.  You should provide the tables structure and sample data.  Then desired output and current output.  Since this is a query question, you could get rid of the PHP and just put the SQL, properly formatted, in the question, it would help readability.

Answer (score 0):

You could alias table name with other name and get column. View example:

```
SELECT C.comment_id, U.user_id
FROM comment C INNER JOIN user u ON C.user_id = U.id
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
SELECT c.post_id,
       c.comment_id,
       c.comment,
       c.user_id AS c_uid,
       c.username,
       c.is_marked,
       p.user_id AS p_uid
FROM comment c
INNER JOIN user u ON c.user_id = u.id
INNER JOIN post p ON c.user_id = p.id
ORDER BY c.comment_id DESC
```

Define aliases for the tables, and the selected fields.  It makes it simpler to read than putting the table names all the time.

In your PHP you can then reference `$row['c_uid']` or `$row['p_uid']`.

Comment: I did something like this. But this is repeating same thing again and again, 5 or 6times

Comment: Without tables and data, I cannot help more.  Provide a [mcve].